# Adding Nextcloud via WebDav Errors Out

Tags: windows, webdav, nextcloud

I have a setup where on the same local network I have Ubuntu 18.04 running Nextcloud on Nginx webserver and another machine that runs Windows 10. I want to add my Nextcloud webdav as a mapped network drive but when I do this I am getting errors:

[error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSYdW.png)

[error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXoXO.png)

[error 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2FJA.png)

Accessing the webdav URL locally via a web browser works, so I can access the webdav by using the following URL:

```
http://[LOCAL_URL]/remote.php/webdav/
```

It will ask for credentials and then display the following message:

```
This is the WebDAV interface. It can only be accessed by WebDAV clients such as the Nextcloud desktop sync client.
```

I have checked and WebClient is running as a Service. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention which version of Nextcloud you are running but according to the manual for r15 here: https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/15/user_manual/files/access_webdav.html , you should be mapping with additional "/dav/files/USERNAME/" at the end of your path string. See the section labeled "Mapping drives with Windows Explorer".